# driver looses focus after closing of child tab and can't perform any action on parent tab

Tags: java, selenium

My Code is like this

```
//Clicking on 'imageRepository' Button opens New Tab.
action.perform(imageRepository, Actions.Click, "",
                "Click on Image repository button");
        ElementsAction.callMeToWait(10000);
        ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        newTab.remove(oldTab);
        // change focus to new tab
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
        selectImage(imageXml);
//After Selecting image Clicking on 'ImageRepositoryPageAddItemButton' closes the new opened tab and automatically gets back to old tab.
        clickImageRepositoryPageAddItemButton();
        //back to old tab
        driver.switchTo().window(oldTab);
        }
```

Now my the driver is not getting focused to old tab. It only waits and perform no action on old tab. How to make driver to focus on old tab?

Comment: what is `oldTab`, where is it assigned ?

Comment: I am working on a tab in chrome browser, consider that as old tab, clicking on a button opens new tab  and after clicking on a button in new tab the new tab closes automatically